# JSF application encounters Target Unreachable, identifier managed-Bean-name resolved to null

Tags: java, rest

Greetings,
I have a simple practice JSF app, using the **h:form** and the **h:inputText** tags and for some reason, the page cannot access the back end managed bean. I have searched the web and there is a myriad of posts on this issue but none I could benefit from to solve this conundrum. I am using Netbeans 12.0, JDK14, and the Glassfish server 5 on Windows 10 platform.

The JSF page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    
    <h:head>
        <title>This is a part number list service</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
     
     <h:form>
         <h2>Hello this is the official part number list service</h2>
         <h3>Please Enter you Role Id</h3>
         <h:inputText id="role"
                      title="My role is"
                      value="#{partNumber.role}"
                      required="true"
                      requiredMessage="Error: You must have an authorized role!"
                      maxlength="25"
                      />
         <h:commandButton id="authorize"
                          value="Authorization"
                          action="showpartnumber" />
     </h:form>
        <div class="messagecolor">
            <h:messages showSummary="true"
                       showDetail="true"
                       errorStyle="color: 20005"
                       errorClass="color: blue" />
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Here is the managed-bean:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class PartNumber {
    private String role;
    private String number;
    
    public PartNumber(){
        number="ML3PY";
    }
    
    public String getNumber(){
        String response="error";
        if(role.equalsIgnoreCase("Part Admin"))
            response =number;
        return response;
    }
    public void setNumber(String n){
        number = n;
    }
    public void setRole(String id){
        role = id;
    }
    public String getRole(){
        return role;
    }
}
```

The web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
   version="4.0">
     <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

I also have a beans.xml file, although, it appears that apps using CDI 1.1 and later don't need it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
</beans>
```

And finally the stacktrace:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /validaterole.xhtml @27,25 value="#{partNumber.role}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'partNumber' resolved to null
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:95)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1122)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:1030)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1334)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:757)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:269)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1298)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1298)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1332)
     ...............................
```

Any insights would be great at this point.
Thanks

Comment: I have defined this already on the JSF page. See the body of my post.

Comment: Razvan, replacing # with $ didn't mend the situation and led to the same error again. In addition, the Java EE documentation suggests using the '#' to access the bean's property through the accessor methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved. The culprit was the auto-generated template header by Netbeans for the web.xml file. I made the following change in the web.xml:
**From:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
   version="4.0">
```

**To:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" 
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
```